# Dynamics 365 - where is everything

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I have installed Microsoft Dynamics 365 trial version, and after searching for two days now, I still haven't figured out. The screen looks like below
[image]

I can't find those ... things which should appear here - something like leads, contacts, accounts, opportunities, or create new record types here. Where is everything...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be a programing question, but rather **using** Microsoft Dyanmics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix this.

**1st** I go through the Admin panel >> Admin Centers >> Dynamics 365
Then select your Dynamics 365 Instance.

**2nd** This works most of the times with my instances and is permanent fix.
In your "https://www.office.com" page.

Click on the Dynamics 365 button that takes you to the empty instance.

Your browser should be saying this:
"https://home.dynamics.com/?autolaunch=true"

Remove "/?autolaunch=true"
so your browser only says "www.home.dynamics.com"
Then press Enter to reload the page.

It might just load you back to the empty instance.

if so then click on Dynamics 365. This will take you to a new page...
press back. so that you end up back at "www.home.dynamics.com/?autolaunch=true"

(I need 10 rep to post more than 2 links in an answer thats why this link has (dot) instead of ".")

Now you should have the options for "Sales", "Customer service", etc..

Also always make sure your user has the right licences.. It should be automatically assigned but you never know...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes a few days to populate that list. try `businessname.crm.dynamics.com/` you should have had to create a new username and business to use dynamics 365 the business name that you used should be what crm uses to populate the url.